# Moving UIImageView frame programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I have UIView, in top of it i have an UIImageView, in bottom UICollectionView. My point is, when user swipe finger up, UIImageView frame should gently move out (disappear), and when user swipe down, it should again appear (with moving animation).

Actually, it worked until i set image to UIImageView. Old code (presented below) did it work just fine:

```
-(void)handleSwipeDown:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    NSLog(@"Swipe received.");
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];

    self.myCollectionView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 152, 320, 480);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

And then:

```
-(void)handleSwipeFrom:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    NSLog(@"Swipe received.");
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];

    self.myCollectionView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

After i set image:

```
UIImage *firstImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ipd1.jpg"];
    self.imageSlideshow.image = firstImage;
```

Code above stop work. UIImage frame stay in same place.
How could i make it move ?
Any advice would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should stop using the `beginAnimations:context:` and `commitAnimations` block.  From Apple's documentation:

> Use of this method is discouraged in iOS 4.0 and later. You should use the block-based animation methods to specify your animations instead.

Use this instead:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    self.myCollectionView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 152, 320, 480);
}];
```

Just replace your entire swipeDown method with the above.

Comment: in the code sample you are moving the frame of myCollectionView, but I assume you need to move imageSlideshow as well?

Comment: Well, in fact in my code imageView wasn't visible but in face, it position is not changed. I just "pull" rest of collectionView up (it was invisible because was below screen).